# Android Studio freezes when getting to Installing APK... (whole AS process, not just the installation)

Tags: android-studio

I've got this issue that Android Studio would completely freeze (not letting me do anything) when getting to Installing APK... part. The only way to fix it is to go to Task Manager (yep, on Windows) and force close it.

It used to do this only once per day or so but in the last few days it started freezing a couple times per day and it's driving me nuts.

I tried increasing the Heap size to 3gb thinking it's running out of memory but when this freeze happens Task Manager only indicates around 1.5gb of usage. Also the hardware isn't a problem.

Comment: did you find a solution, same issue here, makes AS almost unusable :(

Comment: @68060 I started using the Canary one and didn't notice this issue anymore.

Comment: Also seeing the same issue. I am generally installing APKs to an emulator rather than a physical device.